# Dynamic Dependent Drop Down List In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have 3 different tables in database named *productdetails*,*categories* & *subcategorydetails* and likewise I have 3 different Controllers *ProductdetailContoller*,*CategoryController* & *SubcategorydetailController* respectively.
Currently, i'm working on SubcategorydetailContoller's 'view' which is **subcategory.blade.php**

`

```
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">

              <select name="productid">


                <option value="select product">
                @foreach ($productdetail as $row)
                  <option value="{{$row->ProductID}}">
                    {{$row->ProductType}}
                  </option>
                  @endforeach
                  </option>
              </select>

              <select name="categoryid">


                <option value="select category">
                @foreach ($category as $row)
                  <option value="{{$row->CategoryID}}">
                    {{$row->CategoryType}}

                  </option>
                  @endforeach
                  </option>
              </select>

              <input type="text" name="subcategory"/>

              <input type="submit" value="add category"/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>`
```

Now i want to make dynamically dependent drop-down lists but before working for this, I couldn't be able to show the data of second table into second drop-down list.

Here's what i'm doing in my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\productdetail;
use App\category;
use App\subcategorydetail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SubcategorydetailController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {  

       $productdetails=productdetail::all();
        return view('subcategory')->with('productdetail',$productdetails);

        //i wrote this in another class but i still didn't get the desired output
        $category=category::all();
        return view('subcategory')->with('category', $category);

    }



    public function create()
    {

    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data=new subcategorydetail();
        $data->SubCatType=$request->subcategory;
        $data->CategoryID=$request->categoryid;
        $data->save();
        return dd($data);
        //return view('subcategory');
    }
```

Update 1:
Now I got the data on second drop down using this code

```
 public function index()
    {

        $productdetail=productdetail::all();

        $category=category::all();

            /*$category=category::where(DB::table('categories')
            ->join('productdetails','categories.ProductID','=','productdetails.ProductID')
                ->select('categories.CategoryType')
            //->whereRaw('categories.ProductID="1"')
            ->get());*/
            return view('subcategory')->with([
                'productdetail'=>$productdetail,
                'category' => $category,

        ]);


    }
```

Now I'm not getting where I'm doing mistake in joining and establishing logic that when I selected the specific product from first drop down then it would show only categories of that selected product on second drop down??

Update 2:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $productdetail=productdetail::all();

        $data=new productdetail();
        $data=new productdetail();
        $data->ProductID=$request->productid;
        $category=category::where(DB::table('categories')
            ->join('productdetails','categories.ProductID','=','productdetails.ProductID')
             ->select('categories.CategoryType')
            ->whereRaw('categories.ProductID='.$data.'')
            ->get());

        return view('subcategory')->with([
            'productdetail'=>$productdetail,
            'category' => $category,

        ]);


    }
```

The above code showing this error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"ProductID"?}' at line 1 (SQL: select `categories`.`CategoryType` from `categories` inner join `productdetails` on `categories`.`ProductID` = `productdetails`.`ProductID` where categories.ProductID={"ProductID":null})

Comment: `//i wrote this in another class but i still didn't get the desired output` What is the expected output on this? First we need to solve the first problem to be able to go to the second one

Comment: when i select product on first drop-down then it should show the categories of that specific product on second drop-down.

Comment: Either you return all the results at once or you will need to make an ajax request to get the options of the second dropdown whenever the user selects things from the first dropdown. You will need javascript in both ways which you do not have any code written yet. Try something with javascript and edit the question

Comment: well, i have to do it without using ajex or jquery.

Comment: HTML does not provide such option itself. You will need javascript to control the flow. One solution would be:

on your routes add `{productDetail}` and on the controller you will need to get only the categories that has anythign to do with that product detail

`$category=category::where(...); // use the productDetail in here`

Comment: Well, i got the little idea. Thanks for this.

Comment: I added an answer explaining my solution. Mark it as correct answer if that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not provide such feature as dicussed in the comments with you.

What you can do is something like this:

in your routes file

```
Route::get('{productDetail}', 'SubcategorydetailController@index');
```

on your controller action

```
 public function index()
    {  

       $productdetails=productdetail::all();

       $category=category::where(...); // insert the logic to return only the categories that has anything to do with this product detail
        return view('subcategory')->with([
          'category' => $category,
          'productDetail' => $productDetails,
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: {productDetail} why we use this in routing? and what is this line actually doing? 'productDetail' => $productDetails???

Comment: `{productDetail}` is going to get the first parameter of that route. Lets say you have the following route: `1/foo/bar`, `productDetail = 1` here. The second line is the method 'with' accepts an associative array

Comment: Well my second drop down list getting the data without using {{poductDetail}}; my half problem is solved following your guide. Now, I'm not able to establish the dependence of second drop down list on the first drop down list

Comment: Can you describe step by step what you need? From what I understood this should happen: 1. User selects something from the first dropdown 2. 2nd Dropdown is updated and only the options related to the first dropdown are shown

Comment: exactly that's what i need.My problem is, second dropdown showing all the data not depending on the first dropdown. I've updated my question and in last section I showed how i did 'joining'.

Comment: No, I know how to do this thing with JS. I'm given the task that doing this thing without JS.

Comment: The only way to do this without JS is to use the provided approach I gave you. The second dropdown will only have data related to the `{productDetail}`